# Android Sharedpreferences passing value of variable

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

How can I pass the value of the variable to other class? I'm using `SharedPreference` and I don't know if im passing the right value to other class. Here's my statement.

```
if (arr != null) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length();i++) {
        listdata.add(arr.get(i).toString());
        String money = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("amount");
        sum += Integer.parseInt(money);
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(sum), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref1.edit();
    editor.putInt(String.valueOf(sum), sum);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Here is how I get the `SharedPreference` in other class. Is this right?

```
 SharedPreferences sharedpref1 = getContext().getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(""), MODE_PRIVATE);
 int budgeted = sharedpref1.getInt(String.valueOf(""), Integer.parseInt(""));
```

Comment: the preference file name should be same while you fetching sharedPreference.  For your case, these two are differnet if sum is non empty : String.valueOf(sum) & String.valueOf("")

Comment: Or, the way is using default sharedPreference like this : 

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Comment: but its a variable? and not presented in the other class?

Comment: each sharedPreference will be a file in your application data. So, when you pass String.valueOf(sum), it will create a file name of the value sum. So, next time if you want to get the stored data, you need to access same "sum" preference file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharedPreference` is basically a key-value pair stored locally in the application package storage. So you might pick a tag for your `SharedPreference` in your application. Lets say, your `SharedPreference` tag is `MySharedPreference`.

So in case of storing a value in your `SharedPreference` you need to do this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref1.edit();
editor.putInt("TotalSum", sum);  // Pick a key here. 
editor.commit();
```

And when you're retrieving the preference value from some other class, just do this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpref1 = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreference", MODE_PRIVATE);
int budgeted = sharedpref1.getInt("TotalSum", 0); // Use the same key you used before to retrieve the data.
```

Comment: Great to know that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use listener to pass data from one class to another

```
CustomListener listener = new CustomListener();
myClass.setOnSumListener(listener);
------
int sum = listener.getSumValue();
```

or you can use event bus lib 
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus